# Core Data accessing relationships with Duplicates

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using the following to get an array of all of the gifts bought for a single person.
`itemName` is the name of the gift and `giftDetails` is a one-to-many relationship with the person. i.e one person has many gifts

```
NSSet *set=[[object valueForKey:@"giftDetails"] valueForKey:@"itemName"];
NSArray *array=[set allObjects];
```

This code is fine unless there are duplicate `itemName`s. After researching I understand that `NSSet` automatically removes duplicates.

So what I am asking is if there is another way to get the `giftDetails` without using `NSSet` as I want to access the duplicates too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *allGiftDetails = [[object valueForKey:@"giftDetails"] allObjects];
NSArray *allGiftNames = [allGiftDetails valueForKey:@"itemName"];
```

should to the trick.

Comment: Cheers man! I had tried the same thing but missed out the `allObjects`, obvious really.